# Which topics of mathematics should I need to learn to be a good app developer?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, mathematical-programming, mathematical-foundations, software-engineering

I'm 29 years old. I couldn't continue my studies after grade 10 due to some financial issues and I didn't have time to practice mathematics. It's been more than 11 years since I left studies. Now I want to continue in the field of programming. I have grasped the knowledge of basic programing concepts like variables, data types, conditional statements and loops etc. I guess the next stages are data structures and algorithms. Here the lack of math skills will make it difficult for me understand the concepts. I want to know which topics of mathematics I need to learn to be able to program for mobile app development. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Start with some 1-st algorithm or data structure - it will show you mathematics needed.

Answer (score 1):

An employer needs *one* person who is good at maths. Unless you go deep into scientific software, 90% of all programming jobs rarely require any mathematical skills at all.

You will sometimes find problems in programming contests that have clever solutions if you have mathematical skills, but often very similar problems have no such clever solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are familiar with algebra. You should be comfortable with the concept of functions. You should be able to recognize and categorize basic functions (e.g., linear, polynomial, logarithmic, exponential). If you are not familiar with exponents and logarithms, I'd study those too. This is because the logarithmic function is frequently encountered when discussing algorithms and their complexities. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For data structures and algorithms, basic algebra, exponential and logarithmic functions, and a basic course or book on discrete mathematics like one by Kenneth Rosen, should get you warmed up.